# Why I can't override ID on <include> tag?

Tags: java, android, include

I'm try to override the ID on  tag, but when I run in the emulator, the app crashes

I use this to see whats wrong https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts#Include , but still crashing... But when I use the ID root, the code works.

```
     <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tb_conversa"
            />

///////// Java Code //////

    import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

    public class ConversaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       private Toolbar toolbar;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversa);

            toolbar=findViewById(R.id.tb_conversa);

            toolbar.setTitle("Usuario");
            toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_arrow_left);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
    }


/////////// Layout Toolbar /////////

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_principal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>`
    </LinearLayout>
```

Just when I changed the ID for toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar_principal) the code works fine. Why I can't change de ID?

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById(R.id.tb_conversa)` returns you Linear Layout that contains Toolbar. I'm pretty sure you can replace LinearLayout with merge tag, that should fix the problem.

Right now your final layout looks like this:

```
<Parent layout that contains include tag>
...
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tb_conversa">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_principal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>`
    </LinearLayout>
...
</Parent>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for answering me, but it's still not working.... Follow the first part the code again

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context=".activity.ConversaActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tb_conversa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"  />
</ RelativeLayout>